# How to sum a selection of columns?

Tags: awk, sum

I'd like to sum multiple columns in a text file similar to this:

```
GeneA Sample  34  7  8   16
GeneA Sample  17  7  10  91
GeneA Sample  42  9  8   11
```

I'd like to generate the sum at the bottom of columns 3-5 so it will look like:

```
GeneA Sample  34   7   8   16
GeneA Sample  17   7  10   91
GeneA Sample  42   9   8   11
              93  23  26
```

I can use this for a single column but don't know how to specify a range of columns:

```
awk -F'\t' '{sum+=$3} END {print sum}' input file> out
```

Answer (score 1):

The easiest way is just repeat summing for each column, i.

```
awk -F '\t' '{
    s3 += $3
    s4 += $4
    s5 += $5
}
END {
    print s3, s4, s5
}' input_file > out
```

Answer (score 1):

In awk:

```
$ awk '
{
    for(i=3;i<=NF;i++)                       # loop wanted fields
        s[i]+=$i }                           # sum to hash, index on field #
END { 
    for(i=3;i<=NF;i++)                       # same old loop
        printf "%s%s",s[i],(i==NF?ORS:OFS) } # output
' file
93 23 26 118
```

Currently the `for` loop goes thru every numeric field. Change the parameters if needed.

Comment: Thanks, this worked great. I printf "%s%s" to printf "\t" "%s%s" to make the output tab delimitated.

Answer (score 1):

```
$ awk -v OFS='\t' '{s3+=$3; s4+=$4; s5+=$5; $1=$1} 1; 
              END  {print "","",s3,s4,s5}' file

GeneA   Sample  34      7       8       16
GeneA   Sample  17      7       10      91
GeneA   Sample  42      9       8       11
                93      23      26
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this.  Note that NF just means number of fields.  And AWK indexing starts with 1.  So the example here has a range of 3 to the last col.

```
awk '{ for(i=3;i<=NF;i++) sum[i] += $i } END { for(i=3;i<=NF;i++) printf( "%d ", sum[i] ); print "" }' input_file
```

If you want fewer columns, say 3 and 4, then I'd suggest:

```
awk '{ for(i=3;i<=4 && i<=NF;i++) sum[i] += $i } END { for(i=3;i<=4 && i<=NF;i++) printf( "%d ", sum[i] ); print "" }' input_file
```

Comment: Thanks, I tried this but it only worked for about half of the columns? I tried the third solution below and it worked well.

Comment: Hi @MeghanRudd, afraid I confused you by answering more than what was asked.  James Brown's and my first solutions are equivalent in summing all the columns (except for the first and second).  I provided a second solution to show how you could further limit the range of columns, which would only sum the third and fourth columns.  Anyway, glad you found help here.